# When I pedal the back wheel doesn't turn

Tags: hub, freewheel

When I pedal my back wheel of my BMX bike doesn't turn.

About a month ago I took my bike to the shop and they said it would be a 200 dollar fix with my tune up.

It all started with a while ago, I had a little of a flat tire and my rim banged on the ground and it started ghost pedaling and then it wouldn't turn the wheel.

Can anyone help me? I can't find how to fix it. It's a problem with the hub, it won't turn the wheel.

Comment: Focus down on the problem, and analyse it.    So the wheel won't rotate freely even when the bike is lifted off the ground?  Is it the front or back wheel with the problem?

Comment: The reliable piece of information here is the opinion of the shop. I concur that it's a 200 dollar fix. If you want a different opinion, you have to describe in detail what diagnostic steps you have taken to isolate the problem. There could be various reasons why turning the pedals won't turn the back wheel. For instance, the effect can be reproduced if the chain is off the front chain ring, sliding around the plastic chain guard. A flat followed by the rim bottoming out doesn't cause a hub failure.  When you pedal, does the chain ring turn? Does the chain move? Do the rear cogs spin?

Comment: Its like something in the hub that womt move the wheel

Comment: I don't see one can "fix" when freewheel/cassette freehub ratchet crawl break except replacing the whole rear hub or the whole wheel.  With $200, I can get good quality brand new wheel and hub.  I wouldn't bother a "fix" if the problem is due to poor quality rear wheel set.  Perhaps you should shoot picture or low quality video to show the meaning of "not turning"

Comment: @rhuari *Please* take the [tour] and read through the [help] so that you can use the site to effectively get the help you're looking for. People are trying to help you for free, but you're not making it easy for them.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the freewheel pawls or springs have failed inside the rear sprocket. You should be able to have the sprocket replaced for about £30.. You could also have the hub and sprocket replaced but this would mean a wheel rebuild which then includes labour rates etc. 
In which case you may prefer to get a decent new rear wheel for £40 - £80 etc. Obviously top branded parts & exotic materials will cost more.